# Is it possible to add Web Parts to the My Profile page of My Site?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Is it possible to personalize the My Profile page in **the same way** it can be done on the My Home page?

[image: My Profile]

I want to remove the default Web Parts and add other ones.
I don't want to use SharePoint Designer or edit any files manually.

Comment: It should be possible to do this if the SharePoint administrators have given you permissions. Having said that, this is not programming-related. I suggest this question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the 'Site Actions' menu at the top-right of the page will allow you to add / remove web parts. Anyone with 'Full Control' over their own MySite (i.e. everyone) should be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I checked on 2 different SharePoint deployments- apparently I have full control over only one of my MySites.